# Does Google spread sheet have a function to obtain the row/column of the current active cell?

Tags: excel, google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

Excel allows to obtain the row/column of the current active cell
by using a function `Cell('row')` or `Cell('col')`.
which gives the row/column value of the last edited cell.

In Spreadsheet, the function CELL is different from that of Excel.
Two arguments are required in Spreadsheet. One is same as Excel ('row', 'column'...)
and the other is the target cell.

Does SS have a function which gives the value of row/col Active cell?

Comment: Use `Row()` and `Column()` functions.

Comment: They return the values of the cell itself. I want to have the values of the selected cell

Comment: Then where do you want to show the value? Can you sample output?

Comment: Actually all cells... What I would like to do is to feature cells which have the same row or  column with the selected cells .   e.g.  color cells where or(Cell('row')=Row(),Cell('col')=Column())  note that Cell () is not defined in Spreadsheet.  https://trumpexcel.com/highlight-active-row-column-excel/

Comment: Aren't you looking for [Range.getRow()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range#getrow) and [Range.getColumn()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range#getcolumn)? Where `Range` is returned by [SpreadsheetApp.getActiveRange()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/spreadsheet-app#getactiverange).

Comment: I wanted to do this https://support.google.com/docs/thread/96419545/highlight-a-selected-row?hl=en.   Range.getRow() returns the value of the cell itself right? I wanted to have the target cell (not cells which need the value).

Comment: `getRow()` returns the row index, not the cell value. Take a look at the answer I posted. I hope this is useful to you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get the row and column indexes of the top-left cell of a range by doing [Range.getRow()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range#getrow) and [Range.getColumn()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range#getcolumn).

You can get the currently selected `Range` via [getActiveRange()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/spreadsheet-app#getactiverange).

Also, if the `Range` is multi-celled, you can get the range dimensions via [Range.getNumRows()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range#getnumrows) and [Range.getNumColumns()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range#getnumcolumns).

Using all this, if you want to select the full row/s of the currently selected cell/range, you can do the following:

```
function selectFullRow() {
  const activeRange = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveRange();
  const rowIndex = activeRange.getRow();
  const numRows = activeRange.getNumRows();
  const row = activeRange.getSheet().getRange(`${rowIndex}:${numRows+rowIndex-1}`);
  SpreadsheetApp.setActiveRange(row);
}
```

Finally, if you want to trigger this when you select a new cell, you can use [onSelectionChange](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers#onselectionchangee) trigger.

Comment: I have to take it. I appreciate it.